# Sending an email with PHP from a local server

Tags: php

I have installed postfix on my ubuntu and have written the below code to send an email from the local server when a button is pressed ( I need to send it from a local server):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form action="email.php" method="post"> 
<input value="Send Email" name="email" type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
$msg = 'Hello, this is an email from  GUI ';
mail('mm@gmail.com','Sample',$msg); }
?>                 
</html>
```

It works totally fine for gmail and I get an email when I press the button. However, when I change the email address to my Thunderbird mail (work mail) I do not get anything.
 This is what I get in mail.log:

postfix/qmgr[1304]: 3C93B1E1B47: removed

But when I send it to gmail I get sent in my mail.log

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder? Error logs?

Comment: from your local server? mail function will not work in local

Comment: @Jay, no error in the log

Comment: @seyed, It sure does. I get emails in my gmail.

Comment: Your work email server might drop the email if it does not pass the validations.

Comment: @AlexTartan, how should I fix it then?

Comment: @Paul, I have seen this one. It is from a live host. I am sending it from a local server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `php mailer` so that it will  work

You must have email address with privilege. Like you hv hosting email...

download phpmailer and add it within your code so that you can send your mail..
here is some rference code which is used by me...

```
<?php

require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

define("MAILHOST",'hostsite  ');
define("MAILSMTPAuth",true);
define("MAILUsername",'hosting mail');
define("MAILPassword",'password');
define("MAILSMTPSecure",'ssl');
define("MAILPort",portno);
define("MAILFrom",'hosting mail');
    $mail = new phpmailer();
    $result = array();

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = MAILHOST;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = MAILSMTPAuth;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = MAILUsername;                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = MAILPassword;                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = MAILSMTPSecure;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = MAILPort;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->From = MAILUsername;
    $mail->FromName = 'Name';
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = " Inquiry Form";

    $mail->Body = "message";           


    $mail->SetFrom('hosting mail address', 'name');
    $mail->addAddress('recieving mail address', 'Name');     // Add a recipient admin


        }
    exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you. I need a button so when I press it the email be sent. In my code the if part does it with mail function how would that work with your code?

Comment: I have download php mailer but not sure about the details of your program. Could you elaborate more. I could not make it work.

Comment: do you hv hosting mail?

Answer (score 0):

Try phpmailer and see if it works out for you.

You can get phpmailer here : https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Add the folder to your working directory and set the path in the code.

Here's my working code

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php"); //path of phpmailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
    $mail->From = "mygmail@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Gori";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // specif smtp server
    $mail->SMTPSecure= "ssl"; // Used instead of TLS when only POP mail is selected
    $mail->Port = 465; // Used instead of 587 when only POP mail is selected
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "mypw"; // SMTP password
    $mail->AddAddress("another@gmail.com", "Henry"); //replace myname and mypassword to yours
    $mail->AddReplyTo("mygmail@gmail.com", "Gori");
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
    //$mail->AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\js-bak.sql"); // add attachments
    //$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip");

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'test';
    $mail->Body = 'test';

    if($mail->Send()) {echo "Send mail successfully";}
    else {echo "Send mail fail";} 
?>
```